# Make groups or folders for organization in Android Studios

Tags: android, android-studio

I have searched and have not come up with anything on how to make a 'Group' or folder in android studios that I can use to just organize my many classes instead of just having them all in the package folder.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Um, make a sub-package? Java does not have the concept of "a 'Group' or folder" of classes other than packages and sub-packages.

Comment: @CommonsWare When you say sub package what exactly is that

Comment: In addition to having `com.blugeni.stuff`, add the sub-package `com.blugeni.stuff.ui`.